# Equivalence Relations Reflexivity

Tags: relations

Consider the relation on $\bf{R}$ defined by $n \simeq m$ if  $(n-m)\in \bf{R}$

To say this is reflexive, I can say: Let $n\in \bf{R}$ and since $n-n = 0$ and $0 \in \bf{R}$ Then $n \simeq n$.

Comment: By $\bf R$ do you mean $\Bbb R$, the real numbers?

Comment: yes, don't know the syntax for the reals

Comment: Bookman Bold is the standard font of the usual suspects, $\Bbb C, \Bbb R, \Bbb Q, \Bbb Z, \Bbb N$, and such.  Accessed by `\Bbb` or `\mathbb` followed by the letter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed.  *If* zero is an element of $\bf R$, then $\forall n\in\mathbf R: (n-n)\in\mathbf R$, which means that the relation $\simeq$ is reflexive.

( This is obviously true if by $\bf R$ you mean $\Bbb R$, the set of real numbers.   It might not hold for some other set named $\bf R$. )

Now, is $\simeq$ symmetric and transitive?